# MediaPlayer воспроизвести из внешней памяти

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Как можно воспроизвести звук, который хранится во внешней памяти?
Файл находтся в папке /data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/files/Download/
Задал путь в setDataSource

```
String soundPath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/Download/sound1.ogg";
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(soundPath));
```

Но при попытке воспроизвести в логах вижу ошибку mediaerror: setDataSource failed.

Comment: `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(soundPath);`

Answer (score 0):

В андроиде есть некоторые путаницы с понятиями External и Internal Storage. Подробнее [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/429338/)

К примеру метод ниже воспроизводит test.mp3 из внешней папки в памяти телефона

```
private void playExternal(){
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {

        Log.i("Path",getExternalFilesDir("Download")+"/test.mp3");

        mp.setDataSource(getExternalFilesDir("Download")+"/test.mp3");
        mp.prepareAsync();
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer::start);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

В логах, при запуске на эмуляторе у меня показывает путь: 
 */storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ru.companyname.foranswers/files/Download/test.mp3*

Для тестирования внешней папки можно попробовать записать в неё какой нибудь файл. К примеру:

```
private void testDir(){
    try {
        DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(getExternalFilesDir("Download")+"/fortest.txt"));
        stream.writeUTF("тестовая строка");
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне пришлось указывать польный путь к файлу ... ```Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Android/data/com.example.myapplication/files/Download/+ file``` ...Только это помогло. Но почему-то оба варианта указывают на 1 путь, но в первом случае выдает эту ошибку "setDataSource failed" @woesss

Comment: Можно посмотреть что возвращает Files.exist для этих папок и записать текстовые файлы с разными названиями по этим путям, должны тогда оба появиться в одной папке. Интересен корень зла) Если вам самому не надоело конечно.